# Where is the "cascading" objects defined in PyCascading

Tags: python, cascading

Many of the Python source code files for the amazing [PyCascading](https://github.com/twitter-archive/pycascading/wiki#pycascading) package have references to `cascading.someobject` in their header.  E.g.

```
from cascading.tuple import Fields, Tuple, TupleEntry
from cascading.operation.aggregator import *
from cascading.operation.filter import *
```

(from [pycascading/helpers.py](https://github.com/twitter-archive/pycascading/blob/master/python/pycascading/helpers.py))

Where is `cascading` defined or installed?

I assume `cascading` is a wrapper to [Cascading](https://www.cascading.org/), but I don't see how the wrapping occurs (forgive my newness to this).  I checked PyPi and `pip install cascading` returned "No matching distribution found".